# Autozoom Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, increment

I'm trying to create an **auto-zoom** but I'm stuck in here.

I have this function

```
panZoom.zoomOut(num);
```

and I need to call it n times with a little delay to create a nice zoomOut effect

I'm using

```
 for(i=0; i<10;i++){
    panZoom.zoomOut(1);
    };
```

But it executes too fast to create an animation.

I also tried setTimeout:

```
function myLoop () {           
    setTimeout(function () {    
        panZoom.zoomOut(1);

        i++;                     
        if (i < 10) {            //  if the counter < 10, call the loop function
            myLoop();             //  ..  again which will trigger another
        }                        //  ..  setTimeout()

        if (i==10){
            i=1;
        }
    }, 100);
};
```

But the action after the setTimeout execute without waiting for setTimeout to finish (and it's obvious I know but there is not delay function.)

How can I make a smooth zoom effect?

Comment: You could possibly use Raphaels animation system depending on the complexity of wha you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        panZoom.zoomOut(1);
    }, 100 * i);
}
```

Comment: I do, but using setTimeout my function continues, and i want it to wait for the loop to finish **and then** continue